# How to send JSON data to a server in android?

Tags: android, json

With all the old methods been deprecated such as http post , response ,http client, string entity etc, i want to know how can i post json data to a server in android in 2017. My app is supposed to register or send JSON data such as email,contact number and password to a server using POST method and in turn server will give JSON response such as status , message and an array named data. Data is an array of only 2 objects (ie token and email). Please Help.

Comment: Use retrofit,volley or httpUrlConnection

Comment: can u provide code please, that will be very helpful. I have tried volley but i dont know how to send json with it , while i was only able to get reponse properly but not able to register.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to try Loopj library for sending Json Data
[you can try this link](https://github.com/loopj/android-async-http) 
and also it is quite easy to undestand 
[You can try another link](http://loopj.com/android-async-http/)

```
try{

        AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();

        obj.put("email",email);
        obj.put("contact_number",contact_number);
        obj.put("password",password);
        entity = new StringEntity(obj.toString());

        client.post(getApplicationContext(), "Your_URL", entity, "application/json", new TextHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.d("LoginActivity","Failed");
                Log.d("LoginActivity","body " + responseString);
            }

            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                Log.d("LoginActivity","data " + responseString);
                try {
                    JSONObject respObj = new JSONObject(responseString);
                    String data = respObj.toString();
                    Log.d("LoginActivity","Data : " + data);
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
    }catch (Exception ex){
        Log.d("LoginActivity","Getting Exception "+ex.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```
    private void registerUser(){
    final String username = editTextUsername.getText().toString().trim();
    final String password = editTextPassword.getText().toString().trim();
    final String email = editTextEmail.getText().toString().trim();

    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, REGISTER_URL,
            new Response.Listener<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,response,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,error.toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            }){
        @Override
        protected Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            params.put(KEY_EMAIL, email);
            return params;
        }

    };

    RequestQueue requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
}
```

Comment: tried that before , not working,  its because it isnt sending json data bro.

Comment: Did you tried volley also? what error are you getting then?

Comment: no error in code , just not able to register. I dont know how do i encode the data as json while sending. i also used hashmaps.